# Ring homomorphism where $g(1)$ is not identity

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

What is an example of a ring $R$ with 1 and a ring homomorphism $g:R\to S$ so that $g(1)$ is not the identity of S?

So my first thought would be $g:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $g$ takes every element in $R$ to $0$. But since any homomorphic image of a ring with 1 is a ring with 1, we have that $g$ cannot be surjective, and it isn't. So would this be right?

Comment: The usual case is where $S=R\times R$ and $g(r)=(r,0)$.

Comment: And no, you're $g$ isn't surjective. Why would you say it is?

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I think I flipped the definition of surjective in my head to where codomain and domain were switched, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example is $R=S=\mathbb Z_{6}$ and $g(r)=3r$.  Also, $g(r)=4r$ works.

---

In general, given rings with identity, $R_1,R_2,$ we can define $R=R_1\times R_2.$ $R$ is a ring with identity, $(1,1).$

Let $R_3=\{(r_1,0)\mid r_1\in R_1\}.$ $R_3$ is a subset of $R$ which is a ring, isomorphic to $R_1,$ but with a different identity, $(1,0),$ from $R.$

This shows that the concept of a subring is a bit tricky. If we are talking about the category of rings with identity, we have to be specific about whether a subring must have the same identity or if the identity can be different.